# Permanecer na mesma aba depois do Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou a desenvolver um website em jQuery. E até agora criei um menu simples com conteúdo a aparecer dentro de divs.

**Menu**

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
    <li class="menu-text"><h4>Titulo</h4></li> 
    <li class="current"><a href="#1" data-id="div1">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" data-id="div2">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3" data-id="div3">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Conteúdo em Div's**

```
<div class="pbox" id="div1"> ... </div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2"> ... </div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3"> ... </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
    if(!($(this).closest('li').hasClass("current"))){
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);
    }
});
```

O único problema da utilização de abas (ou tabs) é que ao dar refresh na página automaticamente volta para a primeira aba, neste caso a **#1**.

Existe alguma maneira de, ao dar refresh, permanecer na mesma aba?

Comment: Você pode resolver isso, guardando o valor/item em exibição em LocalStorage no próprio HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resolução:**

Depois de procurar ajuda no stackoverflow inglês, consegui solucionar o meu problema.  O código final ficou com este aspecto:

**jQuery**

*Selecionar aba:*

```
var menu = $('#menu');
    menu.on('click', 'a', function () {
    var current = $(this).closest('li');
    if(!current.hasClass("current")){        
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    current.addClass("current");

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
    $('#' + id + '.pbox').show(600);
    history.pushState(null, null, '#' + id);
  }
});
```

*Continuar na mesma aba depois do refresh:*

```
var menuId = location.hash.substring(1);
$( document ).ready(function() {
if (menuId) {
    var menu = $('#menu');
    var current = $("li[id='" + menuId + "']");
    if(!current.hasClass("current")){
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    current.addClass("current");
    $('.pbox:visible').hide();
    $('#' + menuId + '.pbox').show(600);
    history.pushState(null, null, '#' + menuId);
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

atualize o hash da pagina ao mudar de aba, então ao carregar a pagina verifique o hash.

```js
var menu = $('#menu');
menu.on('click', 'a', function () {
  var current = $(this).closest('li');
  if(!current.hasClass("current")){        
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    current.addClass("current");
  
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');  
    $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
    $('#' + id + '.pbox').show(600);
    history.pushState(null, null, '#' + id);
  }
});

var menuId = location.hash.substring(1);
if (menuId) {
  $(menu, "li a[data-id='" + menuId + "]").trigger('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
  <li class="menu-text"><h4>Titulo</h4></li> 
  <li class="current"><a href="#1" data-id="div1">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2" data-id="div2">Menu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3" data-id="div3">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="pbox" id="div1"> Conteudo 1 </div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2"> Conteudo 2 </div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3"> Conteudo 3 </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela rápida resposta Tobias.
Mas o código não funciona.
A única diferença no site é que as abas agora funcionam com Ajax e antes estava a funcionar com jQuery.
Penso que a hash não está a funcionar corretamente não sei o porque. Quando dou F5 na página na aba em que estava, ele volta para a primeira mas o link permanece igual (ex. index.php#2)

Answer (score 0):

Usando o bootstrap eu fiz desta maneira:

```
$('ul.nav-tabs li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

$('ul.nav-tabs > li > a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;
});

var hash = window.location.hash;
$('ul.nav-tabs li a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

Comment: Obrigado Denis, mas não estou a utilizar o Bootstrap.  Estou a usar o Foundation.